# Dealing with <= for dates in Oracle

Tags: oracle

So I've come across a weird thing with Oracle where I have the following SQL Statement.

```
Select *
From tblApplicationMessage
Where cntApplicationMessageType = 1
  AND ysnActive = 1
  AND (dtmValidStart IS NULL OR dtmValidStart <= '09 Nov 2017')
ORDER BY cntApplicationMessage desc;
```

The passed in date is '09 Nov 2017'.  The current date is the same.  Clearly, the two should equate to the "=" portion of the SQL.

If this held up truly, I should receive 13 records from my DB (one record was input today ('09 Nov 2017')).  Instead, I receive 12 records, with the one from today not found.

When I changed the format to use to_date, I received a similar issue, even when dialing back to '08 Nov 2017 23:59:59'.

The question I have is simple: is there a better way to do date comparisons in Oracle?

UPDATE: It appears some people are not good at reading and keep suggesting I use to_date for my comparisons.  Let me once again (I had previously said it) right here just so they can maybe get the point about what I'm saying...

I attempted to use to_date for the comparison.  Whenever I did, I was still not getting the results I expected.  Instead, I would still receive 12 records.

Even after rolling back the date to to_date('08 Nov 17 23:59:59', 'dd Mon yy hh24:mi:ss'), it still was not working. I rolled back the date even further to 01 Nov 17, which still did nothing.

I finally gave up on that attempt because it was not working.

Final thought because I've seen this two-three times now:

Using to_date **DID NOT WORK!**  Not to be rude, but after saying two-three times before it didn't work, I would think others would pick up on the fact that it didn't work for me in this situation...

What did work and was accepted as the answer was using TRUNC.  It got me the results I was looking for.  I will be watching to find a better solution, but it is what it is at the moment and it works.

Comment: Is this MySql or Oracle ? These two RDBMS are not the same, please see [About Oracle tag](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/oracle/info) ===>  *Oracle Server is an Object-relational Database Management System (ORDBMS) created by Oracle Corporation. **Do NOT use this tag for other products owned by Oracle, such as Java and MySQL***

Comment: I have removed the [tag:mysql] tag. Stack Overflow has some overzealous algorithms that suggest the mysql tag specifically for virtually any question related to SQL. https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/275170/stop-generic-database-questions-from-getting-mysql-as-a-suggested-tag

Comment: There was no need to be rude there krokodilko...  A simple "please do not use this because..." would have sufficed.

Comment: Well, '09 Nov 2017' isn't a date, it is a string.  Oracle will attempt to convert it to a date data type if dtmValidStart is also defined as a date.  But you really need to use TO_DATE on that string and provide a format model such as 'dd Mon yyyy'.  While doing that, keep in mind that 09-Nov-2017 will have a time component of 00:00:00 so anything in dtmValidStart with time component of 00:00:01 thru 23:59:59 will fall out of the comparison.

Comment: @Stilgar I did actually use to_date during a later attempt (is noted in my post already), which did not work either.  Hence why I am stumped on this one.

Comment: The TO_DATE attempt tried a different date: Why did you dial back to right BEFORE midnight between Nov 8 and Nov 9? It should be '09 Nov 2017 23:59:59' to catch all dates with a "date" part of Nov 9. With that said, the correct way to compare dates is to ALWAYS, ALWAYS use date data type (for example with TO_DATE), and to get everything from Nov. 9 (all times of day), you must compare with < to_date('10-Nov-2017', 'dd-Mon-yyyy') (note both the date and the strict inequality; don't mess with 23:59:59).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you query:

```
 select * from SYS.NLS_SESSION_PARAMETERS
```

You will see that date format consists of date and time, like:

```
 'DD-MM-YYYY HH24:MI:SS'
```

So '09 Nov 2017' would be equivalent to 09-11-2017 00:00:00. When you compare dates, the value your provide will be implicitly converted to format containing time. You should either have that in mind when querying or for example use TRUNC function on date column being compared.

Comment: Thank you very much!  I hadn't thought of using trunc on my date.  Always the simple things, lol.

Comment: @IyaTaisho - Do **not** use `trunc()` on dates, that is a very poor practice. It means one extra function call for every row in your table; and if you have an index on the date column, as perhaps you might if the date comparison appears often in your queries, using `trunc()` on the date column means the index *will not be used*. Instead, compare as I suggest in the Comment below your original question.

Comment: @mathguy As stated before above, that did not work...  I stated in my post initially that when I tried using to_date, it did not work.  This was even after rolling the day back to 1 second before midnight, and even a few days before it still wouldn't work.  Hence why I say it does not work...

Comment: Ah well, you did not show us the complete code snippet and simply performing TO_DATE on a string is a poor choice; one must always be aware there can be a time component on the date and the format of the string you are passing into TO_DATE should always be specified.